# ASYNCIO.Отличие Tasks от Future

Tags: python, asyncio

### Проблема

Вот уже несколько дней не могу понять разницу между объектами Future и Task. Точнее, не уверен что до конца понимаю что и где используется.

### Мое понимание

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) следует, что в asyncio существует три вида объектов курутины, задачи(Task) и футуры(Future)(назовем их так).
Задачи - это курутины выполнение которых запланировано в eventloop.

> When a coroutine is wrapped into a Task with functions like
>   asyncio.create_task() the coroutine is automatically scheduled to run
>   soon

Футуры - это некий объект в котором хранится возможный результат асинхронной операции.

> A Future represents an eventual result of an asynchronous operation

т.е. для того, что бы запустить курутину на выполнение в асинхронном режиме необходимо использовать [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), но зачем тогда нам [ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future)?, который фигурирует во всех примерах кода по asyncio. На англоязычном stackoverflow нашел смежный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753401/difference-between-coroutine-and-future-task-in-python-3-5), но как мне показалось нормального ответа там и нет. Ниже представлен код в котором я использую различные варианты запуска курутин - результат всегда одинаков:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def fetch(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    print(time.time())
    return n

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# coros = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(i)) for i in range(2)]
# coros = [fetch(i) for i in range(3)]
coros = [loop.create_task(fetch(i)) for i in range(2)]
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coros))
print(results)
```

С вариантом 2 и 3 понятно, так как в соответствии с документацией gather преобразует курутины в задачи, а вот зачем тогда вообще используют `ensure_future`. Так же в документации сказано, что лучше использовать `create_task`.

> See also the create_task() function which is the preferred way for
>   creating new Tasks.

Если подытожить, то хотелось бы услышать простое объяснение что такое футура, чем она отличается от задачи и где используется.

p.s. Пока писал вопрос нашел вот такую [статью](https://cheat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/asyncio.html), но все равно не понятно) и еще один смежный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980086/whats-the-difference-between-loop-create-task-asyncio-async-ensure-future-and)

Comment: [asyncio.ensure_future vs. BaseEventLoop.create_task vs. simple coroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342899/asyncio-ensure-future-vs-baseeventloop-create-task-vs-simple-coroutine)

Comment: да, я видел этот вопрос, и перечитал несколько раз, но честно сказать так и не понял..

Comment: task это future, которое используется чтобы выполнять coroutine (Task это подкласс Future). Не путайте coroutine в частности и awaitable вообще.

Comment: @jfs а можете привести пример с Future? где он используется тогда?

Comment: Future это основа, на которой asyncio библиотека построена. Возьмите любую литературу для самых самых начинающих по asyncio.

Comment: @jfs да в том то и проблема, что во всем что я перечитал рассматривается "единый" объект Future\Task.Если Вы понимаете,что это то - наверное на "пальцах" можете рассказать, ну это я по себе сужу.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что именно непонятно, поэтому я попробую упростить ответ максимально, прибегнув при этом к грубым допущениям. Да простят меня коллеги.

Сопрограмма (coroutine) — результат вызова асинхронной функции, представляющий собой *выполнение* этой функции, способное приостанавливаться. Так как в общем случае невозможно определить сколько раз и на какое время выполнение будет приостановлено, невозможно и сказать когда оно будет закончено. Ваш код может либо ждать завершения выполнения сопрограммы с помощью оператора `await`, либо поручить ожидание циклу событий и продолжить свой выполнение.

В первом случае

```
async def callee():
    print('Hello')

async def caller():
    await callee()
    print('World')
```

выполнение `caller` приостановится до выполнения `callee`. В этот момент какие-то другие операции в каких-то других сопрограммах могут продолжаться, но `caller` будет ждать там, где выполнил `await`.

Во втором случае

```
async def callee():
    print('Hello')

async def caller():
    asyncio.create_task(callee())
    print('World')
```

`caller` сразу же продолжит свою работу. Строка "World" будет выведена раньше, чем "Hello". Здесь мы видим, что `caller` поставил циклу событий **задачу** выполнить сопрограмму `callee`.

Но что если, `callee` будет возвращать какое-то значение, которое нужно вызывающей стороне, но не прямо сейчас, а когда будет готово? Вот тут-то на сцену выходят футуры.

Футура (Future) - будущий результат выполнения сопрограммы. Метод `ensure_future` поручает циклу событий выполнить сопрограмму и сразу же, в момент вызова, возвращает футуру, в которой будет значение, но неизвестно когда. Вызывающая сторона может подождать выполнения футуры так же, как ожидало саму сопрограмму

```
async def callee():
    return 'Hello'

async def caller():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.ensure_future(callee())
    result = await future
    print(result + ' World')
```

Или может заняться своими делами, периодически проверяя готовность

```
async def caller():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.ensure_future(callee())
    while not future.done():
        # Какие-нибудь циклические дела
    print(future.result() + ' World')
```

Или установить на футуру колбэк

```
async def caller():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.ensure_future(callee())
    future.add_done_callback(lambda f: print(f.result() + ' World'))
    # какие-нибудь другие важные дела
```

Или может собрать их в список и ждать все. Или не все, а только ту, которая будет выполнена первой, а остальные проигнорировать. Или передать футуру другой сопрограмме, а самой заняться каким-нибудь другим делом. В общем, это "очень полезный горшок, куда можно класть какие хочешь вещи".

Осталось только разобраться, чем отличаются футуры от задач. Ничем не отличаются, по большому счёту. Класс [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) - это наследник класса [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future). А существенная разница между `asyncio.create_task()` и `loop.ensure_future()` только в том, что первой не было до Python 3.7.

Подытоживая: `Task` - это задача, поставленная циклу событий, на выполнение `coroutine`, одновременно являющаяся `Future`, которая представляет собой результат выполнения `Task` когда-нибудь в будущем.

Comment: как всегда, доступно и просто объяснили, спасибо!у меня такое ощущение что asyncio.create_task() добавили в 3.7 что бы упростить понимание библиотеки.т.е. по побольшому счету Task и Future это одно и тоже?

Comment: Добавили его для того, чтобы разные реализации цикла событий могли использовать разные реализации `Task`.

Comment: в ссылке приведённой выше @andreymal приведена [цитата от Guido о том](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555), что если вы знаете, что на входе у вас именно coroutine, а не future, то `ensure_future()`, которая оба типа принимает (с Питона 3.5 любые awaitable), вам не нужна, а можно сразу `create_task()` вызвать (которая только coroutine принимает). Обе функции Future (и подклассы) возвращают. Кстати, [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) с Питона 3.4 доступна.

Comment: *«Вероятно, что строка "World" будет выведена раньше, чем "Hello".»* -- почему вероятно? Контроль в цикл событий не передаётся, значит `print("World")` всегда раньше `print('Hello')` здесь будет вызван (это *кооперативная* многозадачность, здесь нет preemptive threads)¶ Можно упомянуть, что Future это относительно низкоуровневая вещь. Во многих случаях, можно оставаться на уровне async/await и работать только c coroutines.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Сергей, добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как теперь создавать футуры? Я только начал изучать асинхронность и вижу, что метод ensure_future уже вроде бы как упразднён. Я пытался сделать через create_future , но не совсем понимаю, как передать туда какое-либо значение.
Спасибо!